# Error building Omnet++: Cannot build Tcl/Tk apps on Mountain lion

Tags: compilation, osx-lion, omnet++

I'm trying to Compile Omnet++ 4.1 on Mountain Lion. When I type:

```
./configure
```

I get the following error:

> configure: error: Cannot build Tcl/Tk apps, probably due to misconfigured or missing X11 headers or libs. Check config.log for more info!

I remember compiling it on Lion without any problems, any ideas how to get it working on Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a solution for this over on the [omnetpp google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/omnetpp/QYFKVhEe_GE%5B1-25%5D), I'll paste it in here:

> Hi all,
>
> just tried Mountain Lion, which was released yesterday. Unfortunately,
>   the new MacOSX does not include X11 by default. I really HATE this
>   decision. As a result, it does not pass the Tcl/Tk checks when we do
>   ./configure.
>
> After hours of efforts, I finally figured out how to work around this:
>
> 1. download and install XQuartz at http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/
> 2. make a symbolic link at /usr/include: sudo ln -s /opt/X11/include/X11 /usr/include
>
> and you are all set. In 2, you may also set some environment variables
>   accordingly instead of making the symbolic link.
>
> Future OMNet++ releases may consider setting associated environment
>   variables so that the compiler looks for Xlib.h in
>   /opt/X11/include/X11 with Mountain Lion.
>
> Just successfully compiled the simulator and haven't encountered other
>   problems yet.
>
> Have fun, 
>   TS

Comment: Thx a lot :), worked like a charm. Although i searched the omnetpp google group, but i couldn't find it.

Comment: Note that Luis made an edit to the original post that makes the symlink command more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same problem on Linux (ubuntu) a solution is run this in the console:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc g++ bison flex perl tcl-dev tk-dev blt libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev openjdk-6-jre doxygen graphviz openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev libpcap-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing XQuartz is still the solution to overcome this problem.