# WordNet 3.0 won't install on OS X Mountain Lion (10.8)

Tags: tcl, osx-mountain-lion, x11, tk-toolkit, wordnet

When trying to `make` [WordNet 3.0](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/), it exits with error 2. Scrolling up, the following error surfaces:

```
In file included from tkAppInit.c:16:
/usr/include/tk.h:78:23: error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
```

How do we install WordNet on OS X 10.8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by X11 no longer being bundled with OS X from 10.8 (maybe earlier?). The first step is to download and install [xQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org). After this is done, it will have placed X11 headers in:

```
/opt/X11/include/X11
```

But we need them in:

```
/usr/include
```

The easy solution is to just make a symbolic link:

```
 sudo ln -s /opt/X11/include/X11 /usr/include
```

(This was taken from [an SO post on TCL X11 OS-X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924217/error-cannot-build-tcl-tk-apps-on-mountain-lion-omnet))

Now if you run the make/make install within the WordNet 3.0 distribution, it should install without problems.

Comment: Does it need an X11 build? The Cocoa version of Tk is preferred on OSX these days (for obvious reasons) but not every extension package can cope with that…

Comment: Tk isn't actually being reinstalled. The WordNet-3.0 install has Tcl/Tk code that needs the X11 headers though, and those headers are no longer present in new versions of OS X by default.

Comment: I'm running OS X Mavericks 10.9.2, I have installed xQuartz and made the symbolic link as instructed. However, when try to `make` I got 14 error as `stubs.c:43:17: error: no member named 'result' in 'struct Tcl_Interp'
      interp -> result = 
      ~~~~~~    ^` all error seems to come from the same file `stubs.c`. Any idea how to solve this ...

Comment: Just tried this on a new mac with 10.9.2 (Mavericks) and it completed without error (`./configure` followed by `make`). Are you installing WordNet 3.0 with xQuartz 2.7.5?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Best solution is to instal via Brew found [here](http://macappstore.org/wordnet/)

1. Press Command+F and type Terminal and press enter/return key.
2. Run in Terminal app: `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null` and press enter/return key. Wait for the command to finish.
3. `brew install wordnet`